# connecting spagobi to cosmos

Tags: fiware, spagobi, fiware-cosmos, cosmos

I'm trying to connect SpagoBI to Cosmos via Hive JDBC driver.
The connection works but I need to add jar (json-serde-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar) to be able to execute map reduce when querying.

The problem is that spago bi doesn't support multiple queries for the definition of a dataset and therefore I cannot add the jar before executing the actual select (the semicolon is interpreted as part of the path of the jar)

How can I do? 
Is there a way to definitely add the jar so I don't have to add it again every time I query hive?
Is this the recommended way to access cosmos data from spagobi or is there a different one i'm not aware of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach: configuring the ADD JAR statement within the connection to the datasource. Have a look at

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html

Look at connectionInitSqls: you can put the ADD JAR statement there.
Of course this means that you have to configure the connection as a JNDI resource (that is the recommended configuration indeed).
Hope this helps

Comment: I've tried also this approach, adding a resource in server.xml
  <Resource name="jdbc/cosmos" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"
          url="jdbc:hive2://cosmos.lab.fiware.org:10000/xxxx"
          username="xxxxx" password="xxxx" connectionInitSqls="add JAR /usr/local/apache-hive-0.13.0-bin/lib/json-serde-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;"/> but the problem is the same. A query that does not require MapReduce works, but more complex queries don't.