# Create a Hive data source in SpagoBI for FIWARE Cosmos

Tags: hive, fiware, spagobi, fiware-cosmos

We're trying deploy a report to our SpagoBI Server to show data from FIWARE global Cosmos's HDFS via Hive.
The report is generated successfully locally in SpagoBI Studio, showing the HDFS data in the BIRT Report Viewer (once the JARs for the Hive driver were added). This means the connection to the global FIWARE Lab Cosmos instance is correctly configured.

The problem is we can't deploy the same configuration in SpagoBI Server.
We've configured the data source like in SpagoBI Studio, added the Hive driver JARs to the `/opt/spagobi/All-in-One-SpagoBI-5.1-1feb2d97af/lib` but when we try to test the data source via the web interface, we get the following exception:

```
it.eng.spagobi.tools.datasource.service.rest.TestConnection.testDataSource: Error testing datasources
java.sql.SQLException: Could not open connection to jdbc:hive2://cosmos.lab.fiware.org:10000: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:206)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:178)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at it.eng.spagobi.tools.datasource.service.rest.TestConnection.testDataSource(TestConnection.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:178)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:288)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:203)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:127)
    ... 44 more
```

The configuration of the data source looks like this:

[image]

And the driver JARs used are equivalent to the obtained by the following Maven dependencies:

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.2-cdh3u6</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Anybody knows why the connection is failing?

Related questions:

- [connecting spagobi to cosmos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36160692/connecting-spagobi-to-cosmos)
- [Fiware Cosmos Hive Authorization Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120317/fiware-cosmos-hive-authorization-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was a problem with the HiveServer2 running in Cosmos, which crashes from time to time.
Now it works again.

Answer (score 0):

the stacktrace says "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset", and therefore it seems that there's a problem while connecting to Cosmos. Could you verify if the server hosting SpagoBI Server is able to connect against Cosmos on FIWARE Lab?

Hope this helps

Best regards

Comment: Thanks @Davide, but indeed the server has network connectivity with Cosmos. I suspect it's Hive in Cosmos which now seems to be down... I can't connect from anywhere (not even from Cosmos itself).